# Ext.List row goes blank onclick

Tags: ios, extjs, sencha-touch-2

I have used Ext.List in my applciation ,the data which showing in list from JSON. When i click any of the rows its becomes blank except the image in the row.Here the code

```js
var tab = Ext.create('Ext.List', {
    width: 320,
    height: 290,
    id: 'itemList',
    itemTpl: ['<div style="margin:0px;background:#fff;" >'+
       '<table style="margin:0px;padding:0px;height:40px;" width="100%" >'+
       '<tr><td style="padding:2px 5px;width:90%;"><span><img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,{itemImage}" height="42" width="42"/>'+
       '</span><span>{itemName}<br>{itemDesc}</span></td>'+
       '<td style="padding:2px 10px;width:10%;">'+
       '<img src="resources/img/arrow.png" onclick="viewgiftdetails(\'{itemID}\')"/>'+
       '</td></tr></table></div>'].join(),
    listeners : {
        itemtap: function (list, index, item, record, senchaEvent) {
            if (senchaEvent.event.target.nodeName == 'IMG') {
                var data = record.getData();
                var itemID = data.itemID;
                var itemPurchased = data.itemPurchased;
                var imgref=data.itemImage;
                viewgiftdetails(itemID);
                Ext.getCmp('homepnl').setActiveItem({
                    title: 'My item',
                    items: [viewitemspnl]
                }, {type:'fade', direction:'left'});
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Here the snapshot when i click the row the items text goes blank,

[image]

How to disable the color change when clicking the row?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used it myself but have you tried the [Ext.dataview.List.disableSelection](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.2.1/#!/api/Ext.mixin.Selectable-cfg-disableSelection) config option?